# fork_copy error from make

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I've received this message with Netbeans. I use Cygwin and because of university I use an older version. Before installing this older version Netbeans compiled correctly with a recent version of Cygwin. I can compile with Dev-Cpp. Anyone knows how to fix this error?

```
1 [main] make 4064 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0x3AF000..0x3AF040, done 0, windows pid 2660, Win32 error 487
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 391ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

A resource unavailable error during a fork/vfork is typically an out of memory condition.

First thing to check is how much memory is available. You can see this through the Performance tab is Window's Task Manager.

You can see how much memory each process is using by going to the Processes tab, if the display doesn't show Mem Usage, click View > Select Columns, then check Memory Usage.

NetBeans will probably be the biggest user with Thunderbird and/or Firefox vying for second place. If you're using Chrome, type Shift-Escape to open its task manager.

I've seen some people have success with running cygwin's rebaseall.